# can't get passed param from Link to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have this Link in Main component:

```
<Link
    to={'/protected/'+this.state.username }
    //params={{ username: this.state.user }}
    style={styles.navItem_login}
    underlayColor="#f0f4f7">
    <Text style={styles.navItem_login_text}>Protected Page</Text>
</Link>
```

Then in App.js is the route:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} />


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

const Protected = () => <Text style={styles.header}>{this.props.username}</Text>
```

But `this.props.username` returns `undefined`, as well ass `props.match.params.value` or
`props.location`...

How can i get the passed param in the component?. Thanks

Comment: Your link path is `'/protected/:username'`, but Protected component is rendered at `/protected` and hence it is expected for params to be undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your link is supposed to navigate to `/protected/:username`, you need you Protected component to be also rendered at the same route

**Link**

```
<Link
    to={'/protected/'+this.state.username }
    //params={{ username: this.state.user }}
    style={styles.navItem_login}
    underlayColor="#f0f4f7">
    <Text style={styles.navItem_login_text}>Protected Page</Text>
</Link>
```

**App.js**

```
<PrivateRoute path="/protected/:username" component={Protected} />


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

Also since `Protect` is a functional component, you need to access props like

```
const Protected = (props) => <Text style={styles.header}>{props.match.params.username}</Text>
```

Comment: i have this issue too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times May be you can help ;) Thanks!!